# Will low power indicator come up on any os(retropie) if power is low?

Tags: power-supply, power-management, alternative-power

I'm building a portable gaming system and I have a power bank coming in for it

[image]

I want to know if it will indicate a warning if my "battery" is not supplying enough power so I know when to shut it down.

I've seen many things say something should pop up on the top right of the screen but I still can't find out if it will come up while you're in an os of any kind or just specific ones.

I'm sorry for the noob questions but I've only been working with these for pi things for 3 days now and I'm really excited about this game system iv put together

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK This is inserted by the firmware, so should appear on any OS which uses the current firmware. This was introduced with [PIXEL](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/).

Incidentally I don't think this is a reliable "battery" indicator.
As mentioned in [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) this triggers at 4.63±0.07V.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I can understand that. But that won't be a problem since the battery has a level indicator and I just wanted to make sure it would tell me if it wasn't getting the proper power supply. You know, because the battery level will drop but I'm not sure if the output will change or not and if it did the pi would let me know it wasn't getting sufficient power. Again, sorry for the noob questions.